# Runtime Error - SIGABRT unable to find the bug help me with it

Tags: c++, runtime-error, sigabrt

The problem is about a given number N with number of digits in range 1 to 10^5. If provided 2 numbers s and f less than N and s<=f. Need to check the number formed by digits in s to f is divisible by 7 or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string N; cin>>N;
    long long T; cin>>T;
    string sub="";
    long long i,s,f,val;
    while(T--){
        cin>>s>>f;
        s--; f--;
        sub = "";
        for(i=s;i<=f;i++)
                sub+=N[i];
        val = stoi(sub);
        if(val%7==0)
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"sigabrt but my code is all correct" - apparently not.

First rule of debugging: There is bug in the code that *you* wrote, and your job is to find it.

Your code will obviously crash depending on the input. I'd consider debugging the code instead of claiming it must be correct.

Comment: Thank you. Let me put few more conditions which were mentioned. 1<=N<=10^5, 1<=s,f<=N